# Gem::LoadError when starting middleman server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, middleman

I'm receiving a `Gem::LoadError` whenever I start `middleman server`. Apparently my machine can't find or install `nokogiri`. Am I missing something?

Here's my error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.3.3) among 67 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/Wilhelm/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1311:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1314:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `block in gem'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/middleman:22:in `<main>'
```

Here is my ruby `gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 551) [x86_64-darwin14.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Wilhelm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-dev/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Wilhelm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-dev/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Wilhelm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-dev/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/Wilhelm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-dev/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/Wilhelm/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.3.3)
```

Means, you don't have `nokogiri` installed on your machine but some of your other gem is dependant on it. So, you need to install it.

If you are using bundler, add in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '1.3.3'
```

Then, do:

```
bundle install
```

to install `nokogiri`.

If you don't have a `Gemfile`, just do:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.3.3
```

Sometimes, installing `nokogiri` is tricky. Ideally, my above suggestion should work and install `nokogiri` on your machine. But, in case you get any other error, check this page for [nokogiri installation](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

Comment: I actually solved my problem and left the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279133/error-for-gem-install-nokogiri-and-bundle-install-for-middleman-app#answer-32281973) but your answer helped get me there.  I'm not entirely sure what exactly I fixed but if you know and are willing to explain, feel free to leave it below the answer I left in the link above. Thanks a lot for your help.